# Modifying behaviour of default classloader in Java

Tags: java, classloader

I am attempting to load a single class using custom logic (i.e. I want to swap out the implementation of a class in my libraries with a custom version).

I'd like to create my own, custom classloader, which proxies to the default classloader.
However, It appears that my default classloader: `sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader`, is not visible - meaning that I cannot extend it.

Any solutions for creating a single classloader which is robust enough to replicate behaviour of my existing classloader while subbing in one particular class would be much appreciated.

Note that I've tried using

```
Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
current.setContextClassLoader(newOne);
```

However, this appears not to work, i.e., the classes loaded in the thread are not always triggering my custom classloader.

---

CONTEXT

I want invocations of "new LibraryClass()" to use a custom implementation of this class - where the "new ..." invocation is in a jar file which not under my control.

Comment: What about using `URLClassLoader`? You could add your modified version of `LibraryClass` in front of the rest so that the class loader finds it first. Or perhaps override `findClass`.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you want to replace the `LibraryClass` by your custom version using the same fully qualified name, right?

If  the original `LibraryClass` is already on the class path, it will be impossible to do this with a custom classloader due to the classloader hierarchy (see [The Java Class Loading Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html)).

One possible solution is to put the jar, that contains your custom `LibraryClass`, on the very beginning of the classpath. Your custom class will then be loaded in favor for the original one.

This will not work, if the `LibraryClass` is a bootstrap or extension class.